# How to deploy Quarkus Project on Wildfly Server?

Tags: wildfly, quarkus

How to deploy Quarkus Project on Wildfly Server?

As per my understanding, It only gets deployed in Kubernetes or Open Shift but not on server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't deploy Quarkus applications to WildFly. In fact, you could consider Quarkus an alternative to WildFly -- it contains many of the same libraries, such as RESTEasy for JAX-RS, Hibernate for JPA, Narayana for transactions, SmallRye implementations of MicroProfile specifications, etc.

The big difference (well, one of the many big differences) is that if you build a Quarkus application, you get a standalone runnable, not a deployment that needs to be put into an application server. That standalone runnable is a plain old JAR (actually many JARs, one JAR for the application, plus the dependencies) that you run with `java -jar target/myapp-runner.jar`; or it can be a native binary (if you use the GraalVM support in Quarkus).

You can put the standalone runnable into a container image and deploy that image into Kubernetes or OpenShift, but nothing forces you to do that. You can run your Quarkus application on a plain old operating system just fine.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. As currently we have many Integration projects running in wildfly server in different server groups. Is moving all projects (50+) to Quarkus standalone good idea? or do we need Kubernetes for deploying all and better tracking?

Comment: I don't feel qualified to tell if you should move to Kubernetes. Sounds like your projects are already kinda microservice-y, so it might make sense for you. There's plenty of experience with Kubernetes out there, nowadays, so you can search for it, read it, experiment with it, and decide yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Another question. When you say, that you can add standalone runnable to container image does that mean we do not need graal vm everytimes to put into docker. We can simple make quarkus project and just build image using jvm dockerfile i.e native image is not required at all?

Comment: That's correct, you can always run a Quarkus application on a regular JVM (such as OpenJDK). Nothing forces you to compile it to a native binary using GraalVM. Whether that makes sense for you or not, for example due to performance reasons, you need to decide yourself.